# How do I create a set of classes based on the number of grid columns?

Tags: singularitygs

Is there a way to have Singularity automatically generate a set of available classes based on the number of grid columns?

```
$grids: 12;

.span1-1 { @include grid-span(1,1);}
.span1-2 { @include grid-span(1,2);}
.span1-3 { @include grid-span(1,3);}
...
.span11-1 { @include grid-span(11,1);}
.span12 { @include grid-span(12);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup:

```
$grids: 12;
$gutters: .5;

@for $i from 1 through $grids {
    @for $n from 1 through $grids - $i + 1 {
        .span#{$n}-#{$i} {
            @include grid-span($n, $i);
            overflow: visible !important;
        }
    }
}
```